# Android Java - Calling a Method From A Different Class to Delete Data from a Database

Tags: java, android, class, methods

The following method is from the class **DbProvider**:

```
public void deleteVenue(UUID uuid)
{
    mDatabase.delete(VenueTable.NAME, VenueTable.Cols.UUID + " = ?",
    new String[] { uuid.toString() });
}
```

I need to call the above method from the class **VenueDetailsFragment** and more specifically from the onClick method of an Alert Dialog. This code is below:

```
package com.example.musicpro;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.util.UUID;

public class VenueDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private Venue mVenue;
    private Button mDoneButton;
    private Button mDeleteButton;
    private EditText mVenueName;
    private EditText mVenueAddress;
    private EditText mOpeningTime;

    private static final String ARG_VENUE_ID = "venue_id";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UUID venueID = (UUID) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(ARG_VENUE_ID);
        mVenue = DbProvider.get(getActivity()).getVenue(venueID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        mVenue.setVenueName(mVenueName.getText().toString());
        mVenue.setVenueAddress(mVenueAddress.getText().toString());
        mVenue.setOpeningTime(mOpeningTime.getText().toString());

        DbProvider.get(getActivity()).updateVenue(mVenue);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_venue_details, container, false);

        mVenueName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_name_edit);
        mVenueName.setText(mVenue.getVenueName());

        mVenueAddress = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.venue_address_edit);
        mVenueAddress.setText(mVenue.getVenueAddress());

        mOpeningTime = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.opening_time_edit);
        mOpeningTime.setText(mVenue.getOpeningTime());

        mDoneButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        mDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v)
            {

            }
        });

        mDeleteButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(R.string.confirm_dialog)
                        .setMessage(R.string.delete_dialog)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                //I need to call the deleteVenue method here
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
                d.show();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

Essentially, when a delete button is clicked, a dialog appears where the user confirms they want to delete. Once confirmed, the deleteVenue method should be called which removes the venue from the database and returns the user to a list view (instead of the detailed view) of the venues (with the deleted venue no longer listed).

If more code or information will assist please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - I have tried to instantiate an instance of the class and call the method, but for some reason I couldn't get it to work. Possibly was something to do with the parameters that I was stuffing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a field for your `DbProvider`, and set it within your `onCreate` instead of getting the instance whenever you need it.

```
private DbProvider mProvider;
private Venue mVenue;
// ...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    UUID venueID = (UUID) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(ARG_VENUE_ID);
    mProvider = DbProvider.get(getActivity());
    mVenue = mProvider.getVenue(venueID);
}
```

And then use it within your listener.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.confirm_dialog)
            .setMessage(R.string.delete_dialog)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    // Delete the venue with its UUID
                    mProvider.deleteVenue(mVenue.getUUID());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .create();
    d.show();
```